# Pinterest images on page are not showing

Tags: widget, pinterest

I am trying to add a `Pin it` button on a blog page. `AddThis` widgets are being used for this.

But when I try to use the PIN functionality then it is not choosing all the images on my page.

The image tags are as below

> -- Getting Pinned

```
<img src="images/blog/123_3710961211.jpg" class="blog-main-img">
```

> -- not Getting Pinned

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,v2nv1jcqS/VEhanlIJN8hnyDHoT4Z8FfAhX/g8EI9yHfLfPFQAAAA
BJRU5ErkJggg==" data-filename="Victor Vasarely positive negative space pic.png" 
style="width: 521px;">
```

Let me know what is the error? Is it that Pin does not include Data images?
I have tried using another widget also but same result there.

I read somewhere that `img` size should be at least 100×200 but all my pics are greater than that.

Comment: There is a create pin, but that requires the API and I think you need to have the user logged in... https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/#create-pins

Answer (score 0):

pinterest does not support pinning from base64 images, you should be able to set a meta tag to an actual image not displayed on the page however

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/pic.jpg" />`

Comment: From this page it looks like they support base64, but only for logged in users...
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/#create-pins